# How to do sqlite union with the only constraint

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

Sqlite has column A and column B,
A value is not unique, B value is not unique,
but the combination of A and B values is unique, meaning all rows,
may be the same A, but B will not be the same,
or B the same, A is not the same,
That is, each line of A and B will not all the same.
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Could you provide a sample record so we could understand it better?

Comment: What you should do is to tell us what your goal is.